# Forced to run npm install before yarn?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

Strange one today, wondering if you can help.

I recently reformatted my work laptop, and reinstalled all my tooling. Strangely, I'm finding I have to run `npm install` in full, before I can run `yarn` and `yarn sb` (which simply performs our storybook/start process) on new git cloned projects.

Simply running `yarn` as you can observe below, results in an error regarding *Error: Cannot find module './es6.array.iterator'*.

Any ideas why this may be? It appears `npm install` is doing some extra compilation steps yarn is not, I was of the understanding yarn would do everything npm install would do but a little more efficiently.

```
/* TRIED YARN BY ITSELF - FAILED */
PS C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts> yarn   

yarn install v1.22.4
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > material-table@1.66.0" has unmet peer dependency "@date-io/core@^1.3.6".
warning "material-table > @material-ui/pickers@3.2.10" has unmet peer dependency "@date-io/core@^1.3.6".
warning "@storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/api@5.3.19" has unmet peer dependency "regenerator-runtime@*".
warning "@storybook/addon-docs > @egoist/vue-to-react@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^2.6.10".
warning "@storybook/addon-docs > vue-docgen-loader@1.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=4".
warning " > @storybook/addon-storysource@5.3.19" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/source-loader@*".
warning " > babel-loader@8.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=2".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
$ tsdx build
Error: Cannot find module './es6.array.iterator'
Require stack:
- C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\web.dom.iterable.js
- C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\fn\get-iterator.js
- C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\index.js
- C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\tsdx\dist\errors\extractErrors.js
- C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\tsdx\dist\createRollupConfig.js
- C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\tsdx\dist\createBuildConfigs.js
- C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\tsdx\dist\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\web.dom.iterable.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.


/* BUILT EXTRA STUFF */
PS C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts> npm i
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated os-homedir@2.0.0: This is not needed anymore. Use `require('os').homedir()` instead.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

> husky@4.2.5 preuninstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\husky
> node husky uninstall

husky > Uninstalling git hooks
husky > Done
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\jest.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\jest as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\rimraf.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\rimraf as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\semver.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\semver
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\semver as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\semver
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\detect.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\detect-port
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\detect-port.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\detect-port
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\detect as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\detect-port
npm WARN rm not removing C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\.bin\detect-port as it wasn't installed by C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\detect-port

> husky@4.2.5 install C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\husky
> node husky install

husky > Setting up git hooks
husky > Done

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\@babel\polyfill\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 
Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)


> husky@4.2.5 postinstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\husky
> opencollective-postinstall || exit 0

Thank you for using husky!
If you rely on this package, please consider supporting our open collective:
> https://opencollective.com/husky/donate


> jsonpath@1.0.2 postinstall C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts\node_modules\jsonpath
> node lib/aesprim.js > generated/aesprim-browser.js


> @dhi/react-components-ts@0.2.6 prepare C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts
> tsdx build

✓ Creating entry file 18.7 secs
✓ Building modules 1.1 mins
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.16.3","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @egoist/vue-to-react@1.1.0 requires a peer of vue@^2.6.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1 requires a peer of @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1 requires a peer of @typescript-eslint/parser@2.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@6.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-hooks@2.5.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @dhi/react-components-ts@0.2.6 No repository field.

added 291 packages from 79 contributors, removed 188 packages, updated 2114 packages and audited 2414 packages in 334.47s

162 packages are looking for funding
    run `npm fund` for details

found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 moderate)
    run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

/* NOW YARN RUNS FINE - WITH OBVIOUS package-lock WARNING */
PS C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts> yarn
yarn install v1.22.4
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ tsdx build
✓ Creating entry file 7.3 secs
✓ Building modules 12.2 secs
Done in 21.32s.

/* AND WE CAN RUN OUR PROJECT */
PS C:\dev\projects\react-components-ts> yarn sb 
yarn run v1.22.4
$ start-storybook -p 6006
info @storybook/react v5.3.19
info
info => Loading presets
info => Loading presets
info => Loading config/preview file in "./.storybook".
info => Adding stories defined in ".storybook\main.js".
info => Using default Webpack setup.
info => Using base config because react-scripts is not installed.
webpack built 19b2af886909fb20a73e in 53119ms
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                    │
│   Storybook 5.3.19 started                         │
│   26 s for manager and 55 s for preview            │
│                                                    │
│    Local:            http://localhost:6006/        │
│    On your network:  http://172.16.125.17:6006/    │
│                                                    │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
No issues found.
```

Comment: That's strange indeed, but the issue in `yarn` has something to do with `core-js`. I suspect there must be a "global" yarn package that you forgot to reinstall after reformatting your machine. Might that be the case?

Comment: No it shouldn't be :(

Comment: @GONeale did you find any solution here?

Answer (score -1):

try to do:
`yarn config set ignore-engines true`
and then
`yarn`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 